# Cost threshold for parallelism and wait stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, parallelism

We have an Stored Proc on our prod server (SQL Server 2014) that takes 3hr 40m (on a Sunday: low server activity) to run (collection job costs on 220 jobs with each requiring 6 SP calls, so 13200 SP calls and then some aggregating)

On my laptop with cost threshold set to default of 5 it runs in 30 mins. If I set cost threshold to 50 on my laptop it goes to 1hr 10mins (1/3 of time it takes in prod server)

If i set cost threshold on prod server to 25 it drops to 1hr 30mins, but wait stat go through the roof. See attached: green is threshold of 50, yellow is threshold of 25
[image]

Top waits are CXPACKET and SOS_Scheduler_Yield

[image]

I don't have a comparable dev or staging server (CPU's, RAM and Disk), so I play too much with a bunch of settings while i replay a workload

Tow questions

1. Am I better off with a cost threshold of 25 and the high wait stats and 60% performanc gain. Or will the wait stats cause a lot of issues when the load increases
2. Any thoughts on where the bottleneck is and how to solve. my uneducated guess would be CPU (from the blue line in the charts, it's not too high (under 70%) but is it that it can't serve enough threads in parallel?

Comment: Is this sat on a server with more than one NUMA node? Specifications of the server itself would help here. How up to date are your statistics and indexes?

Comment: Parallelism waits will naturally increase with more parallel queries and parallel threads. These CXPACKET and SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits themselves are not a concern, although the CPU consumed by these queries will reduce resources available to other queries. If you want to improve throughput more, address the next wait stat (ASYNC_NETWORK_IO).

Comment: @George.Palacios our serve ris in two processor Xeon ES-2670 @ 2.6ghz. 64 bit OS 133Gb RAm (max memory in SQL is 112GB. all the indexes have auto stats = true, so that would mean they are up to date, right?

Comment: @DanGuzman. for this test I ran locally so the this particular one shouldn;t be afffected by network. That said what's best way to reduce it? We have 10gps connection a the switch

Comment: @DanGuzman that's only correct if you're assuming that statistics are up to date, NUMA nodes aren't being crossed during parallelism etc. There are a number of things that could mean high CXPACKET waits are a problem.

Comment: @mark1234 It may be worth looking at setting your MAXDOP server level setting to the number of cores on an individual NUMA node - I've seen this cause slowdowns. In addition you should check statistics on the relevant tables - this can throw the engine off and cause unnecessary CXPACKET waits - ensure these statistics are up to date.

Comment: How are the server's drives connected to the server? Are the disks in a separate storage system? Are they connected with a 4Gbit / 8Gbit or higher GBIC/SPF? Are the ports on the SAN switches configured for high speeds? As long as the disks are providing enough data, the CPU will have some computing to do. If the throughput is not high enough, then the CPUs won't peak out. On a 8GBit SPF you should see a disk throughput peaking at 1000 MB/s, unless the switch ports are not configured for the same speed.

Answer (score -2):

`SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` and `CXPACKET` indicates that you’ve got contention and that queries are spending a lot of time waiting to get access to a CPU.

Check [MAXDOP](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-handle-excessive-sos_scheduler_yield-wait-type-values-in-sql-server/) and [Cost Threshold for Parallelism](https://www.sqlshack.com/troubleshooting-the-cxpacket-wait-type-in-sql-server/) to determine when the query should be parallelized.